# Replace Windows logon ui (gina) with a win32 application

Tags: winlogon.exe

In fact I'm designing an application that handles the users authentication(verification of user name and password) and grant them access of windows(load windows shell). I need to replace my program with windows logon ui.

I don't talk a about writing a dll and replace it with windows original gina dll, I mean a **proper interactive win32 application** like notepad.exe

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There is already a perfectly good mechanism for logging into a windows xp machine and granting appropriate rights. What benefit could hacking windows and using a custom application provide?

Comment: That interface is goob, but not good enough. i want to completely customise it to suit my users.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what more you require when logging in...or are you talking about customizing appearance?

Comment: I think it's better to answer to the question if you can rather than try to discover what are my intentions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, and there are many Open and Closed source alternatives out there, but they all have their own drawbacks and advantages. I would strongly suggest using a developed implementation than to try and write your own, after all, why re-invent the wheel yet again? It is also likely to be much more stable out of the box than your own developed app as they have had plenty of time to work out all the crashes that messing with gina can cause.

One of the more well known ones is [pgina](http://pgina.org/). Highlights are:

```
LDAP, MySQL, Local SAM, Email and other plugins included out of the box
100% managed code Plugin API Extended and Enhanced Plugin API allows for multiple plugins and additional features
Supports all Windows plaftorms, from XP SP3 through Windows 8 Developer Preview, x86 and x64 - all from a single installer Enhanced stability, improved memory usage and modern standards and practices based code base
```

Without more information about what you actually want and how you intend to implement it, there is no possible way to elaborate any further. In general though, it is possible, but not a very good idea to mess with unless you have a good reason and know precisely what you are doing, otherwise you will open your computer (and network) to security threats and possibly create a very unstable (or unusable) system.